# Compile Error type mismatch QPTools Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Function MyDocumentsDir()
Dim sBuffer As String
sBuffer = Space$(260)
If SHGetFolderPath(&H0, &H5, -1, &H0, sBuffer) = 0 Then
    MyDocumentsDir = left$(sBuffer, lstrlenW(StrPtr(sBuffer)))
End If
```

End Function

I am getting compile error type mismatch. please help

Comment: Please create a [reprex] and mention what line throws the error.

Comment: what is the return type of SHGetFolderPath? if it is a `String` (as the name might suggest) then comparing it to 0 could be your type missmatch? Otherwise, the problem would be with one of your variable assigments. You will need to provide more info for us to help you.

Comment: I dont know where to start, this vba has several module, this started throwing error after we upgraded our office to o365 64-bit

Comment: Shall I post whole code?

Comment: @dj3094 That's a good clue. That means the problem is in the declaration of native methods. Can you show us the declaration for `SHGetFolderPath` ? It should be near the top.